# Make getline() read the right line

Tags: c++, file-io

I have 3 functions that use getline. The first function checks which of the 2 functions to call depending on the first character of a line.

```
iMessage* getMessage(std::ifstream& ifs, char n) {

    iMessage* msg;
    std::string line;

    std::getline(ifs, line, n);

    if (line[0] == 'T') {

        msg = new Twitter(ifs, n);
    }

    else if (line[0] == 'e') {

        msg = new eMail(ifs, n);
    }

    else msg = nullptr;

    return msg;
}
```

And in the twitter / email constructors:

```
eMail::eMail(std::ifstream& ifs, char n) {


    std::string a;

    std::getline(ifs, a, n);

    //do stuff
}

Twitter::Twitter(std::ifstream& ifs, char n) {

    std::string a;

    std::getline(ifs, a, n);
    //do stuff
}
```

The problem is that the constructors are always reading the first line of the file. How do I make it so the constructors are reading the same line as the getMessage() function?

Comment: Why not pass `line` instead of `n` to the constructors?

Comment: @user657267 the way the assignment is set up is like this, ccan't change it

Comment: Since you're using `ifstream`s you can use `tellg` to store the position before you read the line, and `seekg` to seek back again before you call the constructors.

Comment: @user657267 so call tellg in the constructor or the function that calls the constructors? because i can't pass more than the set parameters to the constructor

Comment: Call it in `getMessage`, so the constructors don't have to know anything about it.

Comment: Are you sure the constructors are reading the first line of the file? I'd expect them to read the next line after the one that `getMessage` read. There's nothing that makes them go back to the beginning of the file.

Comment: @Barmar isn't tellg() just an int? it doesn't set the file to the last read line so I would still have to be passing something to the constructor. and yes the constructors are only reading the first line of the file because i went through debugging on visual studio and the 2nd run of the getMessage() reads the 2nd line but the constructor still reads the first line.

Comment: You call `tellg()` before `getline`, then you call `seekg()` in `getMessage()` to return to the beginning of the line before calling the constructor.

Comment: @Barmar could you write an example of that? i don't really understand what that means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getMessage` doesn't need to read an entire line to do its job.  It can look at just the first character.

In fact, there's a function to look at the first character without removing it from the stream:  [`peek()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek).

So the whole thing is as simple as

```
iMessage* getMessage(std::ifstream& ifs, char n)
{
    switch (ifs.peek())
    {
        case 'T': return new Twitter(ifs, n);
        case 'e': return new eMail(ifs, n);
        default:  return nullptr;
    }
}
```

but the return type should be `std::unique_ptr<iMessage>`.  `std::unique_ptr` is very helpful for preventing memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

In `getMessage` you can restore the file position after reading the line:

```
std::streampos pos = ifs.tellg();
std::getline(ifs, line, n);
ifs.seekg(pos);
```

Comment: Yes... as long as the stream is seekable.  Some special files like pipes aren't.